locale claim suddenly not part of Google JWT auth token
As of recently (2 weeks ago), we noticed some users were no longer abe to authenticate to our internal web apps which rely on Google Federation Identity provider. After some investigation, it was discovered that our token validation mechanism requires the locale claim to be present  as part of th JWT paylaod (i.e. to set the preferred language) but this claim was now missing, causing it to invalidate the token as a result.
This started happening with a few users but then progressively spread throughout our organizaton.
So for now, we patched it so that locale defaults to en-US when the claim is not present.
But my question is why did this claim suddenly dissapar from the the authentication token? I've looked everywhere to see if any communication was made by Google where they would have removed this claim from the token but could not find anything.
Can someone explain why this would suddenly be happening?
I've looked at some of the affected user's Gogle profile to see if any of the preferences were changed recently that would prevent this claim to be sent but they were all set to public.
As per this document, the locale claim should be available if name claim is present which it is in this case.
